# Как передать процедуру как параметр процедуры и присвоить TTimer.OnTimer эту процедуру?

Tags: delphi

Код выглядит вот так:

```
...
TOnTimerProcedure = procedure(TSender: TObject);
...
constructor TMyTimer.Create(in_procedure: TOnTimerProcedure);
begin
  fTime:= 0;
  fSystemTimer:= TTimer.Create(nil);
  fSystemTimer.OnTimer:= TNotifyEvent(in_procedure);
end;
...
```

Нужно передать в конструктор моего класса процедуру, которая будет вызывается таймером. Таймер является полем моего класса. Наследование не предлагать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался сам.

```
...
constructor TMyTimer.Create(in_procedure: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  fTime:= 0;
  fSystemTimer:= TTimer.Create(nil);
  fSystemTimer.Enabled:= false;
  fSystemTimer.OnTimer:= in_procedure;
end;
...
myTimer:= TMyTimer.Create(OnTimerEvent);
...
```